# Network card is not working, after installing Ubuntu on my Dell All-In-One 19

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

My original OS was Windows Vista home.

I'm relatively new to Linux, so this is pretty difficult on my end. After looking up other forum topics, I ended up typing `lspci|grep Net` and the result was:

```
04:00.0 Network cotroller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
06:00.0Etheret controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
```

I'm not sure where to go from here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+t and do:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

Detach the ethernet and the wireless should be working.

To be certain the module loads on boot:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modules
```

Add a single line at the end:

```
b43
```

Proofread, save and close gedit. You should be all set.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked like a charm. At this point the wifi will stay after out the computer being on, unfortunately it turns off and disables it again when you restart the computer. I made sure to save the command prompt in a new document for future reference. Thanks again!

Comment: Please see my edit above.